# PHP: '0' being placed at end of HTML string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am getting a '0' at the end of my display which is making the json_encode show an error - "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character
after JSON data at line 1 column 30 of the JSON data"

In the console it looks like - `"<div>nothing to show<\/div>"0`

I have tried to add a `die;` after the `echo` or after the `else` ending tag as I had read that can solve that in another question on SO. However when added to either spot, then the console logs an "empty string". How would I get the 0 to be removed or if `die`  is correct, where does it go?

```
function phpfuncname(){
$html_string = '';
        if($vairable){
            $html_string .= ' <div class="myclass">div content here</div>';
                {else{
                    $html_string .='<div>nothing to show</div>';  
                    echo json_encode($html_string);
                } 
}
```

JQUERY:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    action: 'php_function_name',
                }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                jQuery('#waitlist').html(data.html);
            })
                .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText); 
                alert(error); 
            })
```

Comment: do you mean to have a closing bracket between the two main lines of code?

Comment: That error message is coming from JavaScript. Are you sure there's nothing else being echoed by PHP further down the code?

Comment: @tangentiallyperpendicular yes that is the end of the code just the closing bracket

Comment: @symlink not sure what you mean?

Comment: @user15081222 Look at the very end of your line where you add the string to the other string.

Comment: @user15081222 the first line in your else statement: </div>’;};

Comment: @daedalus `echo json_encode($html_string);` here?

Comment: @user15081222 No, what symlink gave.

Comment: @symlink ah no a left over from my die attempt. It doesnt change the output though. I just tested

Comment: @daedalus, just a left over from copy paste. I removed above and added jquery since someone suggested that could be what it is

Comment: Are you using any output buffering functions anywhere (eg `ob_start()`)? That's the only thing I can think of that would swallow your `echo` when you have `die` after it. For example https://3v4l.org/0Xqn3

Comment: @phil nothing like that. Above the `else` is the `if` which also has a json echo for the if part. That is about all. I had to place a `die` in the `if` because I was getting the same issue from a `foreach` loop there. I cant add the die since it kills the function from ending. If I do add the die, then I get an empty string

Comment: Your code snippets don't match up. Your client-side expects a JSON object response with `html` property but your PHP would not produce that. There's simply not enough here and what is shown is not consistent. I suggest you start **very** small and grow your code from a working base level, eg `<?php echo json_encode(["html" => "<div>Hello, World!</div>"]); exit;`

Comment: @phil should also add I tried adding the line above in the else statement and got empty string. Then I removed the exit and got undefined

Comment: @phil The rest of the code works just fine. This is the last part of this function, the else and getting it to output properly. Because of that, I dont have the ability to take it back and start over. I am not sure why the php would not work? This is a mirror of the way the if portion works. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your json_encode encodes a string, not an array. When your js code recieves the data, there is no data.html, so that's undefined.

Just change that to

console.log(data);

And see your text appear.

To solve, you can do:

echo json_encode( array( "html" => $html_string ) ); wp_die();

to get what you want. Wp_die() is a necessity.

Comment: the wp_die() was key to me solving similar problem.